# How to get the name of caller function?

Tags: javascript

Let us consider this code example:

```
function Bird() {
    var self = this;
    this.getType = function() {
        return self.type;
    };
}
function Eagle() {
    Bird.call(this);
    this.type = "Eagle";
}
function Sparrow() {
    Bird.call(this);
    this.type = "Sparrow";
}
function Bat() {
    Bird.call(this);
    this.type = "Bat";
}

var e = new Eagle();
console.log(e.getType());
```

Here the `Bird` types are correctly set, but I would like to determine the type on `Bird` level. However, to achieve that, I would need to know which function called Bird. However, if I do something like this:

```
function foo() {
    return new Bird();
}
```

then I would like to make sure that `foo().getType()` results in `undefined`. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to determine which function calls `Bird` without setting `this.type`?

Comment: @guest271314, no, in the question I was setting type inside child constructors because a lack of knowledge of determining it dynamically in Bird. Inside Bird type should be initialized if the constructor is not Bird.

Comment: @guest271314, Javier's answer would be correct if he would initialize type like this: if (self.constructor.name !== "Bird") { this.type = self.constructor.name; }

Comment: What is purpose of `function foo(){return new Bird();}` example?

Comment: @guest271314, the purpose is to make sure that type will be undefined if Bird was instantiated as it is and not from a child constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use call:

```
function Bird(self) {
  var type;
  if (self) {
    type = self.constructor.name;
  } else {
    self = this;
  }
  self.getType = function () {return type;};
}
function Eagle() {
   Bird(this);
}
var e = new Eagle();
console.log(e.getType()); // Eagle
console.log(new Bird().getType()); // undefined
```

Comment: You set this.type inside Eagle. The point is to set it inside Bird dynamically.

Comment: function foo() {return new Bird();} console.log(foo().getType()); will return "Bird", which is not correct.

Comment: This is correct:
if (self.constructor.name !== "Bird") {
    this.type = self.constructor.name;
}

Comment: The given example returns "Eagle". I thought is what you were after, wasn't it?

Comment: @LajosArpad _"function foo() {return new Bird();} console.log(foo().getType()); will return "Bird" "_  Returns `undefined`, here.

Comment: No, in the question I have explicitly described that from foo I intend to get undefined, as in that case the exact type of bird is not defined.

Comment: @guest, if you paste Javier's code and that foo code, is it undefined for you? I would be very surprised if that was the case.

Comment: It's a bit weird because Bird is intended to be used statically in some cases and as an instance in others. Anyway, I updated the function to fit the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.constructor.name
```

to get the name of the object.
As @Lojas Arpad suggested, setting type once, so that no need to compare each time.

```js
function Bird(self) {
  var self = this;
  var type = self.constructor.name === 'Bird' ? undefined : self.constructor.name;
  this.getType = function() {
    return type
  };
}

function Eagle() {
  Bird.call(this);
}

function Sparrow() {
  Bird.call(this);
}

function Bat() {
  Bird.call(this);
}

var e = new Eagle();
console.log(e.getType());

function foo() {
  return new Bird();
}
console.log(foo().getType())
```

Comment: this does not return the name of the function

Comment: The result of function foo() {return new Bird();} console.log(foo().getType()); is the incorrect "foo".

Comment: Sagar, your answer is correct, but let's initialize self.type outside getType and return only the value inside getType.

Comment: @LajosArpad can you explain what will be the advantage of that approach?

Comment: With that approach you check self.constructor.name !== 'Bird' once per object, while with the current approach your code will do that checking each time getType is called. If getType is called many times, then it is less performant.